# Number range restriction on a field using js

Tags: javascript, php

Please i have a field that enables user to enter numeric field. Thus,

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" id="first" name="first"  onkeyup="calculate();javascript:checkNumber(this);"  $type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($cur)) ? cur->FIRST  : 'FIRST' ;?>">$
```

I want a number limitation let say from 0-30 on that field where by you can type number above 30.

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" id="first" name="first"  onkeyup="calculate();javascript:checkNumber(this);"  type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($cur)) ? $cur->FIRST  : 'FIRST' ;?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

With Simple Form and input tag you can do:

```html
<form>
Quantity (between 1 and 30):
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="30"><br> </form>
```

Comment: Thanks @ Om Sao. Please cant it be in JavaScript format. Since its a databinded field because the idea is for it to run some immediate calculation. Thanks in Advance